# Adding Camera Rotation Clamp to this Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm a coding noob getting into Unity & C#, and I copied the following code from a tutorial online to get an FPS character and camera up and running:

The controls work great, except it needs something called "camera clamping" added to it so that I can't rotate the camera up or down enough to look behind myself.

This is the script so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private Transform PlayerCamera;
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController PlayerController;

    [SerializeField] private float MouseSensitivity = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float MovementSpeed = 4f;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpForce = 12f;
    [SerializeField] private float Gravity = -9.81f;

    private Vector3 Velocity;
    private Vector3 PlayerMovementInput;
    private Vector2 PlayerMouseInput;
    private float CamXRotation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PlayerMovementInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        PlayerMouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        Move();
        Look();
    }

    void Move()
    {

        Vector3 MoveVector = transform.forward * PlayerMovementInput.z + transform.right * PlayerMovementInput.x;

        if(PlayerController.isGrounded)
        {
            Velocity.y = -3f;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Velocity.y = JumpForce;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Velocity.y -= Gravity * -2f * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        PlayerController.Move(MoveVector * MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        PlayerController.Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void Look()
    {
        CamXRotation -= PlayerMouseInput.y * MouseSensitivity;

        transform.Rotate(0f, PlayerMouseInput.x * MouseSensitivity, 0f);
        PlayerCamera.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(CamXRotation, 0f, 0f);
    }

}
```

What lines of code can I add to this script to give the camera clamping?

Comment: You can try transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, m_TargetPosition, Time.deltaTime * smooth), it is often used to fix the camera

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first line of your `Look()` to the following

```
CamXRotation = Mathf.Clamp(CamXRotation - PlayerMouseInput.y * MouseSensitivity, minAngle, maxAngle) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to fix the camera, you can refer to the following code. Vector3.Lerp() takes as arguments two points and a decimal between 0-1 that represents a position between the two endpoints. The left endpoint is 0 and the right endpoint is 1. 0.5 returns the endpoint between the two points.
Bring the rigTransform closer to the target position in a gradual and slow manner. That is - the camera will follow the player character. thank you, hope it helps

```
   public float moveSpeed;
   public GameObject target;

   private Transform rigTransform;

 void Start(){
  rigTransform = this.transform.parent;
 }

  void FixedUpdate () {
  if(target == null){
    return;
  }
  rigTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(rigTransform.position, 
  target.transform.position, 
   Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
 }
```

}